Какое горячее сочетание клавиш перемещает строчку влево или вправо в VS code?
как с помощью горячих клавиш перемещать строчку влево, вправо? Например, при создании img или ссылки хочу переместить название класса в начало, чтобы вместо этого


<div class="logo">
  <a href="" class="logo__link">
    <img src="" alt="" class="logo__img">
  </a>
 </div>



Было это


<div class="logo">
   <a class="logo__link" href="#" >
     <img class="logo__img" src="" alt="" >
   </a>
 </div>



И возможно ли в настройках VS code как-то изменить, чтобы при создании a, img или какого-либо тэга, сначала шло название класса?
